Problem custom linker script (ld) section that has WX bits
Premise:
I want to compile my Rust code with a custom linker script, cargo uses this script, and compiles and links my binary without any errors.
Problem:
I want to have a custom section in "SECTIONS" of my linker script that looks something like this:
.reserved_block : {
        . = ALIGN(8);
        __object_buffer = .;
        KEEP(*(.reserved_block))
        . = . + 16K;
        LONG(0);
  } : reserved

I defined reserved PHDR, before my SECTIONS label in my linker script, like this:
PHDRS
{
    reserved PT_LOAD FLAGS(5);
}

When I examine my binary under readelf command I get this for my .reserved_block section:
 [19] .reserved_block   PROGBITS         00000000004587fb  000587fb
       0000000000004009  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     1

Can you suggest what I'm missing in my understanding of linker script syntax for LD, so that I have this behaviour?
I tried to add my custom script, and didn't get expected behaviour

Please edit your post to provide a minimal reproducible example of the problem
and state explicitly what is unexpected about its behaviour.
